# Specifying a "fallback" for undefined references in \ref and \cref (plain LaTeX and cleverref)

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

I am using some of my LaTeX files in multiple documents. And thus in some documents my references will be defined and in others not. I would like to have a way to make `\ref` degrade gracefully.

Thus (many years back) I made a package `sref.sty` that allowed references of the form

```
as shown \sref[pre=in,fallback=above]{thm.foo}.'
```

`pdflatex` formats this to "as shown in **Theorem 3.2.1**." if a `\label{thm.foo}` was in the document and to "as shown above." else.

BUT the qualified references "Theorem 3.2.1" is (much better) covered in the `cleveref` package, and I am thinking of re-implementing `sref.sty` using `cleveref.sty`. Or alternatively making an extension to `cleveref.sty` with the functionality  above. Or I may be unaware of an existing implementation of what I need that could be used directly.

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Hello Michael:-)

Answer (score 1):

You can exploit that `\getrefnumber{<label>}` expands to a string that can be customized when the `<label>` does not exist.

The default string is `0`, which might be safe enough, but here I use a different one that's unlikely to appear as a cross-reference.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\setrefcountdefault{DNE}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\sref}{O{}m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { kohlhase/sref } { #1 }
  \str_if_eq:eeTF { \getrefnumber{#2} } { DNE }
   {% no ref
    \l__kohlhase_sref_fallback_tl
   }
   {% call \cref
    \l__kohlhase_sref_pre_tl \c_space_tl \cref{#2}
   }
   \group_end:
 }

\keys_define:nn { kohlhase/sref }
 {
  pre      .tl_set:N = \l__kohlhase_sref_pre_tl,
  fallback .tl_set:N = \l__kohlhase_sref_fallback_tl,
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{existent}
$1+1=2$
\end{theorem}

As shown \sref[pre=in,fallback=above]{existent}

As shown \sref[pre=in,fallback=above]{nonexistent}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As a naive approach maybe you can use `sref` but 'outsource' the non-fallback referencing to `cleveref`. Something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{sref}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\sref@hlink[5][]{%
  \edef\@fallback{#3}%
  \@ifundefined{r@#2}{%
    \ifx\@fallback\@empty% warn about undefined links and show a substitute
      \protect\G@refundefinedtrue\PackageWarning{sref}{reference #2 undefined}%
      \cref{#2}%
    \else%
      \protect\G@refundefinedtrue\PackageWarning{sref}{using fallback for undefined reference #2}%
      \@fallback%
    \fi
  }{%
    #4 \cref{#2}%
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\label{sec}

\begin{figure}
\centering\fbox{A figure}
\caption{with caption}
\label{fig}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\fbox{A table}
\centering\caption{with caption}
\label{tab}
\end{table}

As shown \sref[pre=in,fallback=nowhere]{fig}, see also\sref{tab}\sref[pre=in]{sec}.\\
As shown \sref[pre=in,fallback=nowhere]{fig2}, see also\sref{tab}\sref[pre=in]{sec}.

\end{document}
```

[image]